# Is there an API for retrieving information about search terms (e.g. zero-result searches, etc)?

Tags: magento2, api, search-terms

Couldn't find any information on this. Only v1/search, but that seems to be for simulating searches on the site.

I'm wondering if there is a way (outside of using Google Analytics) to retrieve the search terms in the dashboard.. i.e. 'Top Search Terms', 'Last Search Terms' etc..